# Can't debug SharePoint 2010 on a SP 2010 farm environment

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, debugging

I'm told I can't debug on a farm environment - one admin server, one web server, one SQL database, all separate boxes.  But it seems like something you'd need to be able to do, so I'm looking for another opinion.

Hoping there's just a config change I need to make to permit it?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging on Production environment is not recommended. You should use Logging and capture the event/details.

If you still want to go ahead then copy solution to one of the web front end server. Then do a deployment using Visual Studio. Since its a farm setup activating feature will fail. So you need to login to central admin and then deploy the solution again.

Once this is done, you can attach W3WP process and start debugging.